# How can I tidy up data responses from Google Forms?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, transpose, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Can anyone please help me tidy up Google Spreadsheet data responses after a Google Form with a checkbox has been filled?

When someone attends training, a Google Form is filled which automatically populates a Google Spreadsheet with:

- the training event
- the date of the event and
- all of the employees who attended that event.

There could be a number of employees attending one event so in the form, there is a checkbox giving the option to tick multiple employees. Below is an example of the Google 'Response Form' spreadsheet after the Form has been submitted:

[image: Response Form Example]

The issue is that the Response Form is difficult to look at so I want to tidy it up and make it easy to use the Query function. Ideally, I would like it to look like this:

[image: Wanted Result]

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(IFERROR(SPLIT(D:D, ";"))<>"", "♦"&B:B&"♥"&C:C&"♥"&
 REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(D:D, ";"), "^, ", ), )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♦")), "♥"), 
 "order by Col2", 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow! I have not seen formula with hearts and diamonds before but thank you very much - that worked - awesome!

Comment: those are just unique symbols and their purpose is to cancel self out as a divisor mark